# Ускорение доступа к произвольному элементу большого массива

Tags: c++, оптимизация

Есть программа на c++ в ходе которой необходим расчет суммы элементов массива с определенными индексами(например случайногенерируемыми, распределенными от 0 до размера массива).
Какой оптимальный способ расчета такой суммы?
Массив большого размера и не может быть целиком помещен в кеш. Но даже в таком случае, как описано чтение из памяти занимает меньше времени, чем прямой расчет функции.
Пример кода

```
#define N_Table 1000000
double table[N_Table];
double index_table[1000] 
void fill_table(){
   for(int i = 0; i < N_Table; i++)
   {
       table[i] = some_function(i);
   }
}
void fill_index(){
   for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
   {
       index_table[i] = some_function(i);//быстрая функция, кроме i использует и другие глобальные параметры, которые тут для простоты не приведены
   }
}
int main()
{
    double sum;
    fill_table();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        fill_index()
        for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
        {
            sum += table[index_table[j]];//узкое место программы
        }
        printf("%lf",sum);
    }

 }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72512/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Comment: Не понимаю, в чем смысл второго прохода для суммирования и следовательно массива `index_table[]`. IMHO тот же результат будет получен если выбросить вызов `fill_index()` и сразу написать во вложенном цикле `sum += table[some_function(j)];`. По крайней мере вы экономите как несколько тысяч операций, выполняемых внутри `fill_index()` для организации цикла, так и 8килобайт в кэше данных первого уровня

Answer (score 0):

> **disclamer**
>
> в процессе обсуждения вопроса, автор вопроса поменял его и ответ не соответствует вопросу. Возможно, я удалю ответ

---

Медленное место в данном случае - это вызов rand. В зависимости от реализации в библиотеке, rand может занимать много-много места.

Посмотрим на код

```
rand() * 1000 + 13*rand()
```

здесь похоже на попытку сделать "более случайно, чем просто один вызов rand". На самом деле случайность здесь абсолютно не улучшается (я бы сказал, что она будет где то такой же). Другое дело, что распределение случайных чисел будет немного других (в случае одного rand оно будет скорее всего более-менее линейным. В случае суммы уже не факт).

Поэтому, если только распределение не принципиально, то используйте один rand или сделайте предварительный просчет случайных чисел - это покажет, где узкое место.

Но если нужно постоянно считать суммы случайным образом, то может просто выдавать случайные числа?

Comment: Это не попытка сделать более случайным, это расширение диапазона rand на весь размер массива. Тут такая индексов массива приведена только для примера. В реальной программе индексы рассчитываются по длинному алгоритму, и их расчет все равно занимает меньше времени, чем доступ к памяти.

Comment: а почему не написать тогда просто `rand() * 1013`? или в исходной программе совсем нет rand?

Comment: исправил в коде. в исходной программе совсем не rand

Comment: И теперь мой ответ выглядит странным... И на более важные вопросы не ответили

Comment: Это потому, что надо сначала прояснить в комментариях неясные моменты, а не торопиться с ответом :)

Comment: как бы правилами запрещено выяснение в комментариях.

Comment: [Разве?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw9mB.png)

Comment: А как только появляются нормальные обсуждения - сразу появляется фраза "избегайте длинных обсуждений"

Answer (score 0):

Для оптимизации программы следует отказаться от формата с плавающей точкой для индекса

```
double index_table[1000]
```

в пользу любого целочисленного формата.